# generating id for tr dynamically in XSL

Tags: xslt

In XSL,I want to generate the id for tr dynamically. The id should be the value what ever I will get from for loop.I will be generating a tr inside the for loop.Can any one help me on this? Thanks in advance.

for example,

```
<xsl:for-each select="books/book">
<tr id="">//I want to generate the tr with id as the value  which i got for book
<td></td>
<td></td>
<tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `<tr id="{generate-id()}">`

Answer (score 0):

If your `id` attributes should be set to the inner text of the `<book>` elements, you can do:

```
<tr>
    <xsl:attribute name="id">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:attribute>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

The above can also be abbreviated to:

```
<tr id="{.}">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the number which is inside book or a generated number like 1,2,....,4 for every `book` node?

For the last one use this:

```
 <xsl:for-each select="books/book">
   <tr>
     <xsl:attribute name="id">
       <xsl:number count="book" level="any"/>
     </xsl:attribute>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
   </tr>
 </xsl:for-each>
```

For more info about numbering elements look here: [Dave Pawson XSLT FAQ](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N5758.html) or [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_number.asp)